# Do you know of any papers investigating the practice of "back cracking"?

Tags: physiology, ebm-evidence-based-med, osteoarthritis, popping-cracking-joints

I found a good number of studies investigating the effects and practice of "knuckle cracking", but close to none on other sites of joint cracking/popping.
knuckle cracking appears to be safe, but i don't know if the statement can be extended to other joints.

These are some of the papers i found, and they all refer to the habit of cracking one's knuckles:
https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/36454151/
https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/30080300/
https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/28050816/
https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/21383216/

Only the first paper mentions in passing "severe joint cracking of his knuckles and, at times, **his back**."
To clarify, i'm mostly interest in the habit of self-cracking, like one would do with their fingers, which has been found to have no ill-effects.

Is there any such evidence on back-cracking? habit of self-joint cracking in general

to clarify further: i'm not interested in chiropractice or their "techniques"

Comment: Welcome. It may well be a geographical issue, but I've never heard the term "back cracking"; I suspect your search came short because of the term you use for *the popping noise caused by (chiropractic) manipulation/adjustment of the back/other joints.* Maybe searching for something akin to "When is adjustment/popping of a joint harmful?" or "Which joints are harmed by adjustment/popping?" will yield more information. Please note that this site requires evidence of a search (quote and link.) Thanks. (P.S. The source must be reliable; for-profit sources seldom are.)

Comment: Chiropractors are the providers who practice "back cracking." So the terms you should be looking for are "chiropractic adjustment" and "chiropractic manipulation." I doubt you'll find anything useful searching for "back cracking." As for safety, you should start with [this](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=cervical+spine+manipulation+and+stroke&hl=en&as_sdt=0&as_vis=1&oi=scholart).

Comment: Apologies, i was in a bit of a hurry when i posted this the other day. I have provided more details and some search results.

to answer to @anongoodnurse, i used that term because "cracking" is what i had previously found

Comment: "i'm not interested in chiropractice or their 'techniques'" Then you might, with luck, find a few case reports of harm done, but you won't find any studies due to the nature of the subject (manipulation done by ones self).